# Angular 2 mock Http get() to return local json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, angular

What is the easiest way to mock the response returned by `Http` `get()` in Angular 2?

I have local `data.json` file in my working directory, and I want `get()` to return response containing that data as a payload, simulating the rest api.

Documents for configuring the `Backend` object for `Http` seemed somewhat obscure and overcomplicated for such a simple task.

Comment: No idea why you think configuring `Backend` is obscure. DI is a major and basic building block of Angular2 and this is exactly the use case DI is made for. What's complicated with `MockBackend, provide(XHRBackend, {useExisting: MockBackend})`. It's simple and straight-forward.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Software engineers comes in a variety. Just because something is easy for the top 50 percentile, doesn't make it easy for the bottom 50. It's never good to be so dismissive of another person's POV without actually being in their shoes.

Comment: @KaMok My comment isn't dismissive. If someone wants a solution, he needs to provide information about what the problem is. That was my comment about. "Documents for configuring the Backend object for Http seemed somewhat obscure and overcomplicated for such a simple task." is just useless ranting. If he had provided a link or posted the code he found overcomplicated there had been something to discuss about, but the way it is, it's not really a question. I just tried to get more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `XhrBackend` provider with the `MockBackend` one. You need then to create another injector to be able to execute a true HTTP request.

Here is a sample:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => {
  return [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
    SomeHttpService
  ];
});

it('Should something', inject([XHRBackend, SomeHttpService], (mockBackend, httpService) => {
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
      ]);
      var http = injector.get(Http);
      http.get('data.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({
            body: data
          })));
      });
    });
}));
```

Comment: after a research I found answer to be MUCH simpler: just use location of the local json file (app/data.json) as an url instead of http address

Comment: Great! Interested in having more details ;-) How the request is actually executed?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier the request is executed like any GET request from a real server, but for more nuanced procedures, like testing behavior on requests that arent successful or PUT requests will need MockBackend.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you need to mock the `XHRBackend` and provide mocked data in a class with the `createDb` method. `createDb` method returns the mocked JSON object. To load that data provide correct `URL` to `http.get`, for example, if JSON object is contained in a variable `mockedObject`, then the URL should be `"app\mockedObject"`.

You can read more details here: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HttpTestingController available via the core TestBed as to me it feels more intuitive (each to their own, of course).  Untested snippet:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { MyApiService } from './my-api.service';

export function main() {
  describe('Test set', () => {
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [MyApiService]
      });

      httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    it('should call get', async(() => {

      const data: any = {mydata: 'test'};
      let actualResponse: any = null;
      MyApiService.get().subscribe((response: any) => {
        actualResponse = response;
      });

      httpMock.expectOne('localhost:5555/my-path').flush(data);
      expect(actualResponse).toEqual(data);

    }));
  });
}
```